# Finding an inverse laplace transform for $\frac{a}{\left(s^2 + a^2\right)^2}$

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

I am asked to show that $x'' + w^2x = f\sin(wt)$
has a solution given by $x = \frac{f}{2w^2}(\sin(wt) - wt\cos(wt))$
where $w$ and $f$ are constants, by means of Laplace transforms.

By taking a Laplace transform of each side, I get that $ L(x)(s) = \frac{wf}{(s^2 + w^2)^2}$

Here's where I'm stymied. My problem lies in taking the inverse Laplace to find the solution; I have found a couple inverse Laplace functions that appear in http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Laplace_Table.aspx, but I'm uncertain how to manipulate my result into one of those forms.

What's more, the textbook for this class (curse it) has a remarkably limited table. The closest pairs it has would be the pairs for $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$.

if I leave $w$ in, then I can get $\frac{w}{s^2 + w^2}\frac{1}{s^2 + w^2}$ where the first term resembles the $\sin(t)$ transform, but I don't know if I'm just chasing rainbows with that...

I thought of adding and subtracting a value but I always end up with $1 + something$ (I've pulled the $wf$ out as a constant before the transform) as a numerator, and I'm not sure what to do with that.

So ... how do I do this inverse Laplace transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you have to use the result $\mathcal L[t\, p(t)] = -\dfrac{d}{ds} \mathcal L[p(t)]$.

Using this:

$\mathcal L[t \cos \omega t] = -\dfrac{d}{ds}\mathcal L[\cos \omega t] = -\dfrac{d}{ds} \dfrac{s}{s^2 + \omega^2} = \dfrac{s^2 - \omega^2}{(s^2 + \omega^2)^2}$

This can be split up as:

$\dfrac{s^2 + \omega^2 - 2\omega^2}{(s^2 + \omega^2)^2} = \dfrac{1}{s^2 + \omega^2} - \dfrac{2\omega^2}{(s^2 + \omega^2)^2} = \dfrac{1}{\omega}\mathcal L[\sin \omega t] -\dfrac{2\omega^2}{(s^2 + \omega^2)^2}$

Thus:

$
\mathcal L[t \cos \omega t]= \dfrac{1}{\omega}\mathcal L[\sin \omega t] -\dfrac{2\omega^2}{(s^2 + \omega^2)^2} \Rightarrow\\
\mathcal L\left[\dfrac{1}{\omega}\sin \omega t - t \cos \omega t\right] = \dfrac{2\omega^2}{(s^2 + \omega^2)^2}$.
$

Multiply by $\dfrac{f}{2\omega}$ and you get $\dfrac{\omega f}{(s^2 + \omega^2)^2}$.

Comment: I don't recall that L(tp(t)) = -d/ds(L(p(t)), where is that coming from?

Comment: Nevermind, found it in my electrical engineering textbook. But not my differential equations book. Bah.

Comment: I didn't even consider working it from the solution x(t) backward. Probably should have been the first thing to try after I got stuck trying to inverse laplace, when I knew what I was supposed to get.

Comment: There does appear to be an error: your derivative should be w^2-s^2 in the numerator, though I think I can work from there.

Comment: @DanielBall The derivative has $\omega^2 - s^2$, but the transform is negative of the derivative, so it becomes $s^2 - \omega^2$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e1kq7n09ked